# Gradle get zip fullpathname to upload via ssh

Tags: java, plugins, ssh, gradle

I'm a very beginner in Gradle and need some help!

I'm using the plugin java-library-distribution to build a zip file for my project.
I'm using also the plugin org.hidetake.ssh to upload my .zip file on my remote server.

It works perfectly well but I need to write manually the full pathname of my zip file (/Users/myLogin/Documents/Java-Dev/TestApp/build/distributions/MyServer-1.0.zip) into the "put" command (see example below)

Is there a way to get it from the java-library-distribution plugin when the task distZip is executed?

```
task deployFull(dependsOn: distZip) << {
    ssh.run {
        session(remotes.webServer) {
            put from: '/Users/myLogin/Documents/Java-Dev/TestApp/build/distributions/MyServer-1.0.zip', into: './'
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Sébastien.

Comment: You can use `${projectRoot}` (I think this is the name); that will refer to the root of the project. I'm also pretty sure there is a variable for the `build` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, just use `distZip.archivePath`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is even better because it includes also the name of the .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to replace the full pathname because I can simply use the variable $project.distsDir.

put from: "$project.distsDir/$archiveZipName", into: './'